# Vertical align text dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Title of of the album is dynamically generated from admin panel.

So the problem is when titles are not the same length.

They are used for navigating (prev and next) below actual album...

Code:

```
<div class="album-box">
    <div class="prev-album pull-left">
        <a href="">Dynamically generated title</a>
    </div>
    <div class="next-album pull-right">
        <a href="">Dynamically generated title in
            Dynamically generated title 3
            Dynamically generated title rows</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Live:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/58eh0r2g/)

Not sure how can I position it to be in the middle vertically no matter how long the title is.

Any idea?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I would like to move elements on the left and right border. 
Image:
[image: img]

Comment: See if this thread can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17539410/3630431

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got plenty of good answers.

Here's one more using `display:table`

### [Non-flexbox Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/58eh0r2g/8/)

```
.prev-album, .next-album {     
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding: 20px 0;
  color: red;
  display: table;
}

.album-box a{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution as a flexbox alt :)

Comment: One more question: prev titles should be position the left like when I use position absolute and then set the left 0, and the next title should be positioned to the right edge. How can I do it?

Comment: Just change the text alignment or you meant something else? [View Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/58eh0r2g/9/)

Comment: No, I meant somehow to move that `a` tag box or something... so text should be centered but that box should be moved left and right.

Comment: Best i can think of is add more padding. But you can't have it both ways - aligned to one side and centered at the same time. There will be some white space. https://jsfiddle.net/58eh0r2g/15/

Answer (score 2):

Use `flex`: https://jsfiddle.net/58eh0r2g/1/

Add the following code to the parent containers.

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

In your case these would be `.prev-album` and `.next-album`

https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

This solution will lose support for some IE versions, but `flex` is so powerful it's worth using it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to grasp a new and awesome css...thing, then I would use flexbox. Flexbox has a property called align-items that will vertically align flex items (children).

Read here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Browser support is growing, but mobile and IE10 will need -ms- or -webkit- prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Give the next-album and prev-album `display: table;`
Then add `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` to the anchor tags inside of those divs.

I also updated your jsfiddle to show my answer.
https://jsfiddle.net/58eh0r2g/7/

Answer (score 0):

You can set css display attribute of the album-box class to `table`, and child to `table-cell`, then you can use `vertical-align: middle;`

Or you could try display `flex`, but it's not supported by some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

*This has been asked in various forms all over Stack Overflow but here you go, Simply add this to your CSS:*

`.prev-album a, .next-album a {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle; 
}`

Then change `display: inline-block` to `display: table` on both `.prev-album` and `.next-album`.

- Simple update of your existing code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SimonHayter/58eh0r2g/11/)
- Several improvements to your existing code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SimonHayter/58eh0r2g/14/)

You could even opt to use [flex box](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/) method however older browsers will not support it, especially internet explorer. You can view the browser [support for Flex Box on caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

*You could simplify your CSS by sharing properties as it will reduce code and be easier to manage:*

```
.album-box, .prev-album, .next-album {
  border-color: green;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0;
}

.album-box {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
}

.prev-album, .next-album {     
  font-size: 12pt;
  height: 82px;
  display: table;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.prev-album {
  border-right-width: 1px;
}

.next-album {
  border-left-width: 1px;
}

.prev-album a, .next-album a {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution different from the ones posted so far:

**[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/damo_s/rw45pe04/2/)**

Using a combination of `transform` and `top`/`left` with absolute positioning on the `a` tags (absolute relative to parent):

```
.prev-album, .next-album {     
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding: 20px 0;
  color: red;

  // added this
  position: relative;
}

// and these
.prev-album a, .next-album a {
  padding: 10px 40px;     
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to align the text dynamically in the center of vertical axis, try using the follows:

HTML:
    
        Content here

CSS:
    #parent {display: table;}

```
#child {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I have modified your code s per above in this plunk : http://plnkr.co/edit/PdK9YWGUvbuGAW7S00x9?p=preview